# Implementing digital controller in the time domain

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, digital-communications, control-systems, software-implementation

I have simulated a digital control system in the Z domain using MATLAB and I have got satisfactory results. However, when I converted the plant and the digital controller to difference equations and implemented them in an m-file, I did not get the same results displayed in the Z domain

In the Z domain, my system is stable and the response to a unit step met certain desired specifications, but in time domain, the response goes to infinity:

Below you find the program in the Z domain then in the time domain:

1. Z domain simulation:

```
clear all
close all

J = 0.01;                           % moment of inertia of the rotor       0.01 kg.m^2
b = 0.1;                            % motor viscous friction constant      0.1 N.m.s
K = 0.01;                           % electromotive force constant         0.01 V/rad/sec
                                    % motor torque constant                0.01 N.m/Amp
R = 1;                              % electric resistance                  1 Ohm
L = 0.5;                            % electric inductance                  0.5 H
s = tf('s');
P_motor = K/((J*s+b)*(L*s+R)+K^2)   % Open loop Transfer function of a Dc motor Speed/Voltage
zpk(P_motor)

%rP_motor=0.1/(0.5*s+1)              % First Order approximation of P_motor
Ts = 0.05;
dP_motor = c2d(P_motor, Ts, 'zoh');

zpk(dP_motor)

sys_cl = feedback(dP_motor,1);
[y,t] = step(sys_cl,1);
stairs(t,y);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: Original')

Kp = 100;
Ki = 200;
Kd = 10;

C = Kp + Ki/s + Kd*s;
PI=Kp+Ki/s;
PD=Kp+Kd*s;
dC1 = c2d(C,Ts,'tustin')
dPI=c2d(PI,Ts,'tustin');
dPD=c2d(PD,Ts,'tustin');

sys_cl = feedback(dC1*dP_motor,1);
[x2,t] = step(sys_cl,12);
stairs(t,x2)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: with PID controller')

rlocus(dC1*dP_motor)
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1 1])
title('Root Locus of Compensated System')

z = tf('z',Ts);
dC = dC1/(z+0.82);
rlocus(dC*dP_motor);
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1 1])
title('Root Locus of Compensated System');


sys_cl = feedback(0.8*dC*dP_motor,1);
[x3,t] = step(sys_cl,8);
stairs(t,x3)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: with Modified PID controller')
```

Unit step response according to this simulation:
[image]

2. Time domain simulation (using difference equations)

```
close all;

%Output initial condition
yk=0;yk_1=0;yk_2=0;
%Controller initial condition of 
uk_3=0;  uk_2=0;  uk_1=0;  uk=0;          
%Error initial condition
ek_3=0;  ek_2=0;  ek_1=0;  ek=0;  
%Sampling Time
Ts=0.05;

%Desired output (unit step)
yd=1;

%Stokage of different variables (yk, uk and time)
stokuk=[0];
stokyk=[0];
temps=[0];

%******Z Transform of the plant*****%
%     0.002059 z + 0.001686         %
%     ----------------------        %
%     z^2 - 1.511 z + 0.5488        %
%                                   %
%***********************************%

%***Z Transforme of the Controller**%
%    404 z^2 - 632 z + 244          %
%   -------------------------       %
%   z^3 + 0.82 z^2 - z - 0.82       %
%                                   %
%***********************************%



%Calculation of 
for t=[0:Ts:12]
    t;
    
    ek=yd-yk;
    uk=(404*ek_1)-(632*ek_2)+(244*ek_3)-(0.82*uk_1)+(uk_2)+(0.82*uk_3);
    yk=(1.511*yk_1)-(0.5488*yk_2)+(0.002059*uk_1)+(0.001686*uk_2);
    yk_2=yk_1;
    yk_1=yk;
    uk_3=uk_2;
    uk_2=uk_1;
    uk_1=uk;
    ek_3=ek_2;
    ek_2=ek_1;
    ek_1=ek;
    
    stokyk=[stokyk;yk];
    stokuk=[stokuk;uk];
    temps=[temps;t];
     
end

plot(temps,stokyk);grid on
hold on
plot(temps,stokuk);grid on
```

Unit step response in the time domain:

[image]

Could anyone please explain to me why I get this difference in simulations?

Comment: I suspect you have a parasitic delay in the implementation not captured in the model. You can find this by single stepping through both simulations and comparing the result after each step and then dig into the code to explain the  difference and ensure you captured all the unit sample delays properly in the model for the system as you simulated to be causal

Comment: That little downward hitch at the 2nd sample in the response indicates that you've designed a _really_ ambitious controller -- that's consistent with one extra time-slot of delay being the problem.